# How to select every element in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Is it possible to select every element of the web page loaded in ?
I have simlple code:

html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe id="frame" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $("#frame < *").hover( function () {
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid blue");
            return false;
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).css("border", "none");  //  unmark the paragraphs
        }).click( function () {
            //click actions
    });
});
```

Comment: you'll have absolutely no luck if the iframe is not in the same domain as the containing document ... and `<` means nothing in CSS

Comment: If it is same domain: https://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: @JaromandaX: jQuery selectors do support the parent operator, but that isn't actually useful here anyway.

Comment: Thanks to everybody.